# chop `%` from an output produced by `dh -H` command

Tags: ruby

I am new to scripting, I am trying to write a simple script for sensu check to create an alert for Disk Space.

The below command produces an output:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
a =  `df -h / | grep -v "Filesystem" | awk '{print $5}'`
puts a
```

Assume that the output is `35%`

now I want to strip down the `%`, when I try using `a.chop!` still it is not removing the `%`

Could some one please help me stripping off the `%` from the output.

Comment: You could use 2 chops, one for new line char, another for % at the end. Try `a.chop!.chop!`

Comment: Use `a.to_i`, it ignores extraneous characters

Comment: `a.chop!.chop!` made me laugh! +1

Answer (score 1):

The value returned from your command has a newline at its end:

```
a
# => "35%\n"
```

To remove the `%` using `chop` you need to [`strip!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-strip-21) it first:

```
a.strip!
a.chop!
# => "35"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're going to use this in a numeric comparison just convert it to an integer in one step:

```
a =  `df -h / | grep -v "Filesystem" | awk '{print $5}'`
puts a.to_i
# => 66
```